# nuget restore suddenly stopped working properly for mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/sdk docker image

Tags: .net, docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci, nuget-package-restore

I am using this docker image to build my .net projects

```
mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/sdk
```

And these are the final lines to build the project in gitlab ci

```
- nuget restore temp\src\Watson.ConnectivityServer\Lib\Swc.EL.Interfaces\Swc.EL.Interfaces.csproj
- msbuild temp\src\Watson.ConnectivityServer\Lib\Swc.EL.Interfaces\Swc.EasitraxLive.Interfaces.csproj /p:Configuration=Release
```

Till two three days back it was working fine. It suddenly started giving me these errors since yesterday

> Assets file
> 'C:\builds\engineering\e-connect\swc\watson\temp\src\Watson.ConnectivityServer\Lib\Swc.EL.Interfaces\obj\project.assets.json'
> doesn't have a target for 'net451'. Ensure that restore has run and
> that you have included 'net451' in the TargetFrameworks for your
> project.

Nothing was changed anywhere.

After a lot of head banging I could figure out that `nuget restore` line is causing the issue. Somehow nuget is not able to restore the packages properly.
Because when I use `dotnet restore` it works fine. So basically when I replace the restore line with this, it works perfectly

```
- dotnet restore temp\src\Watson.ConnectivityServer\Lib\Swc.EL.Interfaces\Swc.EasitraxLive.Interfaces.csproj
```

What could be the reason it suddenly stopped working? Could it be some change in the docker image?

Just the add the point my project targets multiple frameworks, and looks like it is failing only for projects with multiple target frameworks

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <TargetFrameworks>netcoreapp2.0;net451</TargetFrameworks>
</PropertyGroup>
```

But the same thing was working earlier for these projects also!

Any leads?

Comment: The `sdk` image was updated to use the VS 16.8 Build Tools on Nov. 10. It's possible this is what caused this to stop working. Can you verify this by using the previous version of the `sdk` image? You'll need to know which version of Windows you're running in order to target the correct tag. For example, if you're running the latest version of Windows 10, version 2009/20H2, you'll want to use `sdk:4.8-20201020-windowsservercore-2009`. Just replace `2009` with whatever version of Windows you're running. If that works, please log an issue at https://github.com/dotnet/msbuild.

Answer (score 0):

For PowerToys, we hit this issue recently.  In our CI, we shifted from NuGet 5.5 to 5.8 and it restored again.

Here is the PR
https://github.com/microsoft/PowerToys/pull/8142